# Remove space on textbox but not between words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove spaces on the beginning of text on textbox on keyup event but will not remove spaces if it is between text. how can i do that?

Comment: that is what trim is for - it removes the whitespace at the beginning and end of a string.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: yes, and it would remove spaces even between texts.

Comment: i tried trim but when i type another word with a space it would remove the space after i type.

Comment: The problem is not with trim, but with when you are doing it.  You need to do it when the text box loses focus.

Comment: @rjx44: trim is used to remove the leading and trailing spaces from a string. when you type space after your first word and execute trim function, it will obviously consider the space as a trailing space and removes it

Comment: Is it possible @StefanH to do it only on keyup?

Comment: @SunilKumarBM so it is not possible to trigger that on keyup event?

Comment: @rjx44: I really don't think it is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I strip white space when grabbing text with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360491/how-do-i-strip-white-space-when-grabbing-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">

String.prototype.ltrim = function() {
return this.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
$(function(){
    $("#idOfTextBoxHere").keyup(function(){
      $(this).val( $(this).val().ltrim());
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You could also prototype against jQuery ($ instead of String) if you prefer that route. The top three lines extend strings to have a new method allowing them to be left trimmed of spaces. The definition following that only executes once everything is loaded, and assigns a handler to left trim on key up.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i don know your exact need ple correct me

```
        $('#your textbox id').keyup(function () {

            var val = $(this).val();                
            val = val.replace(/^\s+/, '');              
            $(this).val(val);


        });
```

Comment: i want to remove spaces on textbox on keyup event but don't remove spaces between words typed in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression

```
/^\ //
```

to remove the space at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

use the `trim()` function

```
var text = "   hel  lo ";
alert(text.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#idOfTextboxHere").focusout(function(){
    $(this).val( $.trim($(this).val()) );
});
```

When the user clicks away, it will trim the beginning and end of the textbox.