# Remove whitespaces inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, trim

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript) about javascript trim, with a regex answer.

Then I expect trim to remove the *inner* space between Hello and World.

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello World ".trim());
}
```

**EDITED**

**Why I expected that!?**

Nonsense! Obviously trim doesn't remove inner spaces!, only leading and trailing ones, that's how trim works, then this was a very wrong question, my apologies.

Comment: trim removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: Trim removes whitespace from *before* and *after* a string.  `Hello World` is already "trimmed'.

Comment: @void: That's not "trimming", that's a different problem.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text

Comment: Heh.. "obviously" trim will trim something but not from the "middle" ...  you need a stripping instead of trimming.. a nice regex like someone already pointed out :-)

Answer (score 394, accepted):

For space-character removal use

```
"hello world".replace(/\s/g, "");
```

for all white space use the suggestion by Rocket in the comments below!

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes! the correct answer! though this might be slightly more efficient: str.replace(/\s+/g, '')

Comment: @RocketHazmat : what do u mean by other white spaces? '.replace(/ /g, '')' this will remove all white spaces right?

Comment: @PitchiahNatarajan `\s` will match spaces, tabs, and new lines.

Answer (score 56):

You can use

```
"Hello World ".replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

`trim()` only removes trailing spaces on the string (first and last on the chain).
In this case this regExp is faster because you can remove one or more spaces at the same time.

If you change the replacement  empty string to '$', the difference becomes much clearer:

```
var string= '  Q  W E   R TY ';
console.log(string.replace(/\s/g, '$'));  // $$Q$$W$E$$$R$TY$
console.log(string.replace(/\s+/g, '#')); // #Q#W#E#R#TY#
```

Performance comparison - `/\s+/g` is faster. See here: http://jsperf.com/s-vs-s

**Update**

You can use too:

```
console.log(string.replaceAll(/\s/, '#')); // #Q#W#E#R#TY#
```

[String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800402/215552) does the same thing. Please present some relevant tests indicating this is faster than that answer by anything more than nanoseconds.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Updated!

Comment: Thank you for the example, made it crystal clear what the difference is doing.

Comment: please update your answer with replaceAll

Answer (score 16):

The best way is to do it this way if you only want to replace the whitespaces:

```js
let str = " H e l l o 1  5 9   ";
let onlyCharacters = str.replaceAll(" ", "");

// onlyCharacters = Hello159
```

I used `str.replace(/\s/g, "");` a lot but it does not work in all the browsers for example it does not work in duckduckgo in android and also it does not work in android webview.

Answer (score 12):

Probably because you forgot to [implement the solution in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498995/250259). That's the code that makes `trim()` work.

**update**

This answer only applies to older browsers. Newer browsers apparently support `trim()` natively.

Comment: Not necessarily, some browsers have it built in. :-P

Comment: Its present in most modern browers now -> http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 6):

You can use Strings [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a regular expression.

`"Hello World ".replace(/ /g, "");`

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a
>   RegExp

[RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

- **/ /** - Regular expression matching spaces
- **g** - Global flag; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match

```js
const str = "H    e            l l       o  World! ".replace(/ /g, "");
document.getElementById("greeting").innerText = str;
```

```html
<p id="greeting"><p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive solution:

```js
function removeWhitespaces(string, i = 0, res = "") {
  if (i >= string.length)
    return res
  else
  if (string[i] == " ")
    return removeWhitespaces(string, i + 1, res)
  else
    return removeWhitespaces(string, i + 1, res += string[i])
}

console.log(removeWhitespaces(" Hello World,   how is it going ? "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Precise answer to how to approach this depends on precise intention. To remove any and/or all white space characters you should use:

`'s t r i n g'.replace(\s+\g, '')`

If the intention is to only remove specific types of whitespaces (ie. thin or hair spaces) they have to be listed explicitely like this:

`'s t r i n g'.replace(\ |\t \g, '')`

However if the intention is to remove just plain spaces only, then performance wise the best solution is:

`'s t r i n g'.replace(' ', '')`

---

[Here](https://jsbench.me/drlfuphfhk/1) is a benchmark comparing results. There is a slight performance variance amongst the regexp solutions, but its rather insignificant. However string based replace outperforms regexps in the linked benchamrk by about an order of magnitude of ops/s. (https://jsbench.me/drlfuphfhk/1)