# Is there any case in which replace method fails to remove white space from the string?

Tags: javascript, replace

look at the following question:

[Remove whitespaces inside a string in javascript [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript)

according to the accepted answer `string.replace(" ","")` will remove all the white space

but in my case i have the following string:

```
var ctr = " #d1 { width: 100px ; height: 100px ; background-color: #000 ; opacity: 1 ; margin-left : 0px ; } "
```

now i tried to replace all the extra white spaces:

```
 var ctrWithNoWhiteSpaces = ctr.replace(" ", ""); //returns spaces full string
```

```js
function s(){


var ctr = " #d1 {       width: 100px ; height: 100px ; background-color: #000 ; opacity: 1 ; margin-left : 0px ; } ";
  
  alert(ctr);
  
  ctr = ctr.replace(" ", "");
  
  alert(ctr);


}
```

```html
<button onclick="s()">click</button>
```

i don't know why it is not working for me?
or **is this is one of the cases in which replace method fails to remove whitespaces from the string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace() only replaces the first occurrence. Here's one way to replace all occurrences:

[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex by passing `\g` global modifier:

```js
function s(){
  var ctr = " #d1 {       width: 100px ; height: 100px ; background-color: #000 ; opacity: 1 ; margin-left : 0px ; } ";            
  
  ctr = ctr.replace(/\s/g, ""); // \s means whitespace      
  alert(ctr);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="s()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no...

Try:

```js
function s(){
var str = " sanm sai s dj  k df  ";
str = String(str).replace(" ", "");
  
  alert(str);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="s();">click </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer would be to use:

```
stringName.replace(/ /g, "")
```

This will replace all occurrences of spaces. All spaces, however, are not strictly all of the whitespace, so for all whitespace you could alternatively use:

```
stringName.replace(/\s/g, "")
```