# Check if body tag is empty in text representing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

This [URL](https://servizigis.regione.emilia-romagna.it/wms/rete_escursionistica?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=Percorso_escursionistico&LAYERS=Percorso_escursionistico&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=1066907.1242551755%2C5606702.129269345%2C1128668.243109598%2C5668463.248123767) seems to bring to an empty HTML but looking at its source (`CTRL+U`) there's some style in it.

However, the `body` tag is empty and I would need a way to test it given that the only thing I have is the source representation as text (see below).

I've been reading [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385518/1979665) which might be of help but so far I could not find a proper way to apply it.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><html xmlns:esri_wms=\"http://www.esri.com/wms\" xmlns=\"http://www.esri.com/wms\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></meta>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\ttable, th, td {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tborder:1px solid #e5e5e5;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tborder-collapse:collapse;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-family: arial;\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-size: 80%;\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcolor: #333333\r\n\t\t\t\t\t} \t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tth, td {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tvalign: top;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\ttext-align: center;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tth {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbackground-color: #aed7ff\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body></body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Comment: How about checking `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Are you trying to run a check to see if there is HTML source code in the body?

Comment: @www139 something like that. Consider I don't have a DOM element but only a text var representing a "HTML web page" (as in the example).

Comment: Instead of trying to work from your linked answer, look further down that question for usrbowe's answer and work from that.

Comment: @Alohci I think it is exactly what I need. Will try that asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `innerHTML` property of all HTML tags:

```
var text = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><html xmlns:esri_wms=\"http://www.esri.com/wms\" xmlns=\"http://www.esri.com/wms\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></meta>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\ttable, th, td {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tborder:1px solid #e5e5e5;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tborder-collapse:collapse;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-family: arial;\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tfont-size: 80%;\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcolor: #333333\r\n\t\t\t\t\t} \t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tth, td {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tvalign: top;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\ttext-align: center;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tth {\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tbackground-color: #aed7ff\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body></body>\r\n</html>\r\n";
text.slice(1, -1);
var body = document.body;
body.replace(/ /g, "")

if (body == "") {
    console.log("Empty page"!);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write but I couldn't quite understand the question (+1).

Comment: No worries, I gave you +1

Comment: Might want to trim that in case of whitespace inside tag

Comment: OK, now strips whitespace - thanks @RocketHazmat for your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @JBDouble05 But how can I getElementsByTagName if I don't have a "document" but a text representing a document as I showed in my example?

Comment: The page source you gave us isn't a string, it's HTML.

Comment: There will only ever be one `body` tag so why use `getElementsByTagName()` only to extract the one element that is in the node list? Not to mention that `.getElementsByTagName()` has performance issues. Use `.querySelector("body")` or just `document.body` instead.

Comment: @JBDouble05 "given that the only thing I have is the source representation as text (see below)" this is my issue

Comment: @umbe1987 Just strip off the double quotes and you'll have a HTML page.

Comment: It works. If you could add this in your answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. How did you strip the quotes?

Comment: text.slice(1, -1);

Comment: Added. That better?

Comment: @JBDouble05 I',m really sorry. It does only remove the first and last char but it still remain a string. First and last char being "<" and "\n". Sorry again....

Comment: How do you think I'd fix that?

Comment: The expected behaviour of my app was to not show a message if body is empty. That was what happened using slice but I didn't notice a console error.