# How to make Joi regex() validation fail if the string contains " " (whitespace)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have the a vehicle registration number being validated by Joi in Node.js and need it to reject any string that contains whitespace (space, tab, etc.)

I tried the following schema, but Joi does let it go through:

```
  const schema = { 
    regNo: Joi.string()
     .regex(/^.*\S*.*$/)
     .required()
     .trim()
    }
```

So, if I submit "JOI 777" the string is considered valid.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your first part of you regex is going to match anything,.   I think what you want is a lot simpler, match any none-whitespace  `/^\S+$/`  ,  IOW:  if a whitepace appears it should fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your regex -> `/^.*` is saying match anything, so the rest of your regEx is pretty much short circuited.

So your RegEx is a bit simpler,  `/^\S+$/`

This is then saying, from the start to the end, everything has to be a None whitespace..  Also seen as this checks everything for whitespace, you could also take out your `.trim()`..

eg.

```js
const tests = [
  "JOI 777",  //space in the middle
  "JOI777",   //looks good to me
  "  JOI777", //space at start
  "JOI777 ",  //space at end
  "JO\tI77",  //tab
  "ABC123",   //another one that seems ok.
  "XYZ\n111"  //newline
];

tests.forEach(t => {
  console.log(`${!!t.match(/^\S+$/)} "${t}"`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for skipping whitespace from string just use:

```
"hello world".replace(/\s/g, "");
```

if you have more than One space use this :

```
"this string has more than one space".replace(/ /g, '');
```

for more detail see this link below:
[Remove whitespaces inside a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `if you have more than One space use this`, your first one will remove multiple spaces too,..   Your second one will ONLY remove spaces, not tabs / newline etc.

Comment: tnx for the tips I realized now

Comment: This doesnt really answer the person's question. They are looking to have joi reject a value not modify incomming values.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the answers. Yes, the answer provided by Keith worked as needed within Joi. Much appreciate everyone's attention!

Comment: This answer is rather irrelevant. He doesn't want to remove whitespaces instead he want to raise validation error. This is especially important for password fields. Maybe Joi should implement a method to disallow a special character in a string.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
export const authenticateValidation = Joi.object({
    last_name: Joi.string()
      .alphanum()
      .min(1)
      .required(),
})
```