# JavaScript: Add space between Char and Number with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I have a plate number `BZ8345LK` and want convert to `BZ 8345 LK` (adding space between char and number).

I tried with this Regex but not working, only space first char with number. Ex `BZ 8345LK`, the '`LK`' keep not space with number.

```
var str = 'BZ8345LK';
str.replace(/[^0-9](?=[0-9])/g, '$& ');
# return BZ 8345LK, I want BZ 8345 LK
```

Comment: here is explained why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
[a-z](?=\d)|\d(?=[a-z])
```

- `[a-z](?=\d)` - Match any alphabet followed by digit
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR
- `\d(?=[a-z])` - Any digit followed by alphabet

```js
let str = 'BZ8345LK'

let op = str.replace(/[a-z](?=\d)|\d(?=[a-z])/gi, '$& ')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: This best choice in dynamic text input like on change.

Comment: Can you force remove extra space in number `BZ 83 45 LK` to `BZ 8345 LK`

Comment: If number format `BZ83 45LK`, how to keep output `BZ 8345 LK`

Comment: @Puyup First [strip out the spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800402/5527985) then use the answer.

Comment: @Puyup you can simply remove all the  space `str.replace(/\s+/g,'')`

Answer (score 2):

You should alternate with the other possibility, that a number is followed by a non-number:

```js
var str = 'BZ8345LK';
console.log(str.replace(/[^0-9](?=[0-9])|[0-9](?=[^0-9])/g, '$& '));
```

Comment: If used in text input with onChange this code add more extra space each char and number.

Answer (score 0):

An anoher option is to use:

```
^[^\d]+|[\d]{4}
```

Search for any not numeric character `[^\d]` followed by 4 numeric `[\d]{4}` characters

```js
const str = 'BZ8345LK'
let answer = str.replace(/^[^\d]+|[\d]{4}/gi, '$& ')
console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```js
var str = "BZ8345LK";
var result = str.replace(/([A-Z]+)(\d+)([A-Z]+)/, "$1 $2 $3");
console.log(result);
```