# How can I compare two strings ignoring new line characters, white spaces, non-breaking space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare two strings ignoring white spaces, newline characters, non-breaking space.
Strings should be equal.

> moves the cursor down to \r\n    \r\n  the next line without
> returning.
>
> moves the cursor down the next          \r\n \r\n the line without
> returning.

Comment: Just strip them out and compare the result?

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of them with a simple regex.

```
const pureString = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

And then do your comparison between the two string.

In the regex you are replacing all the `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` in your string with `''`, so with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the two strings of all the characters you want to ignore.

To strip a string of all the characters you don't want you can use the replace() function. By using \s we remove all spaces, tabs and new-lines, if you want something more specific you have to change the first argument of the replace() function.

```js
string.replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

(see this SO-question to understand how it works: [Remove whitespaces inside a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript))

To compare two strings you could use

```js
string1.localeCompare(string2)
```

(see this SO-question to understand how it works:
[Optimum way to compare strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript) )

If you put these two concepts together, you get

```js
string1 = string1.replace(/\s+/g, '')
string2 = string2.replace(/\s+/g, '')
string1.localeCompare(string2)
```

which should answer your question.