# Assigning string into the button every time page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this code successfully shuffles the phone numbers order every time pages refreshes. What I'm trying to do is create a Call us button that selects a phone number from the "var = arr" array and assign that to the button but when page refreshes assigned number from the button has to be changed so that way customer could call a different number every time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }

  var arr = ['<div class="class1"><a href="tel:+17866331938"><p>+1 786 633 19 38</p></a></div>',
    '<div class="class2"><a href="tel:+17866331298"><p>+1 786 633 12 98</p></a></div>',
    '<div class="class3"><a href="tel:+17866331903"><p>+1 786 633 19 03</p></a></div>',
    '<div class="class4"><a href="tel:+17865741168"><p>+1 786 574 11 68</p></a></div>'
  ];
  arr = shuffle(arr);
  arr.map(function(k, v) {
    $(".div-wrap").append(k);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: What's the question? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your array should contain phone numbers, not elaborate HTML structures.
2. `forEach` is a better method here. You don't need keys, and you don't need a new array.
3. We'll simply remove whitespace characters for the `href` attribute values.
4. Anchors should not contain paragraphs. While it may be allowed by HTML5 spec, it's an odd arrangement.
5. [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). I love jQuery and used it heavily back during the dark ages of browser standards, but it's less and less necessary.

Key concepts:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Whitespace removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800355/remove-whitespaces-inside-a-string-in-javascript)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }

  var arr = ['1 786 633 19 38', '1 786 633 12 98', '1 786 633 19 03', '1 786 574 11 68'];
  arr = shuffle(arr);

  arr.forEach(function(v) {
    const el = `<p><a href="tel:+${v.replace(/ /g,'')}">+${v}</a></p>`;
    document.querySelector(".div-wrap").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can I assign these phone numbers into a button that can make a direct call with an click.

Comment: They are, as shown above. Did you click them? That's what `tel` does. You wouldn't use a button. That's the wrong type of element for that action. You can, however, _style_ the anchors as buttons.

Comment: And please do take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers on this site.