# jQuery strip spaces out of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to strip all the spaces out of the contents of my array.

Here is my array

```
var array = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
```

I've tried using the answer found here: [how do I strip white space when grabbing text with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360491/how-do-i-strip-white-space-when-grabbing-text-with-jquery)

This is what the jQuery I'm trying to use.

```
$(array1).each(function(entry) {
  $(this).replace(/\s+/g, '');
  console.log(entry);
});
```

But it throws a `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'entry.replace(/\s+/g, '')')`

What am I missing?

Comment: Try not to use any jQuery at all for this task, and it will work.

Comment: @Bergi is it faster to not use jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map to make a new array.

In the map function, you use the regexp on your value.

---

## jQuery

```
array = $.map(array, function(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wx701j/);

---

## Vanilla JS version

```
array = array.map(function(value){
  return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wx701j/1/)

---

## Old IE vanilla JS

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  array[i] = array[i].replace(/ /g, '');
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wx701j/2/)

---

## No loop universal method (may have conflict with characters)

```
array = array.join('$').replace(/ /g, '').split('$');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wx701j/3/)

Comment: Notice that your "old IE" version does something different than the `map` solutions

Comment: @Bergi You lost me there, what do you mean?

Comment: The one modifies the array object, the other replaces the `array` variable.

Comment: @Bergi Oh ok, yeah indeed it does then!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jQuery here, just go with plain array methods like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or simple for-loop:

```js
var array1 = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"].map(function(el) {
    return el.replace(/\s*/g, '')
});

document.write(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is not what you want, you want `entry`, that's your string

`entry = entry.replace(/\s+/g, '');`

Also actually your string is the second argument. So you'd need to change your function to `function(key, entry)` also

That's why it doesn't work, but I recommend using some of the other solutions here. `$.each` isn't the best option, you want to `map`.

Comment: Entry is an array index. First parameter past to function is index second is element.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize jQuery was so weird.

Answer (score 0):

This simple for loop, loops through the array items and removes any spaces no jQuery or regular expressions needed.

```
var arr = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i].replace(' ', ''));
}
```

Comment: However, whitespace (`/\s+/`) is something different than blanks (` `)

Comment: could you provide me an example?

Comment: Simple: `var arr = ["option\x0a1", "option\t2", "option\n3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how 'each' works in jQuery, it is not quite what you think.  This code can be fixed by noting that the first parameter to your callback is the index into the array, and so you can adjust the code like so.

```js
var array1 = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]

$(array1).each(function(entry, value) {
  array1[entry] = value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  console.log(array1[entry]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $(array1).each(function(a, b) {
  array1[a] = b.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});