# PHP file_get_contents() function

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I tried first example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
<?php
   $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.scibet.com/');
   echo $homepage;
?>
```

I only get this:

```
Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\test.php on line 2

Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 22 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\test.php on line 2

Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 19 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\test.php on line 2

Notice: file_get_contents(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\test.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.scibet.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\test.php on line 2
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to read the entire site?

Comment: Yes, i need way to get all content from external url...

Comment: Try stream_get_contents instead // only works if fopen is allowed on the site's server and in PHP5+
 $handle = fopen("http://websiteyouwanttoscrape.com/file.html", "r"); 

 $contents = stream_get_contents($handle); An example on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834038/php-find-and-get-value-based-on-another-one-from-html-table-parsed-file/34835046#34835046

Answer (score 0):

Your setup may have allow_url_fopen not set up. You need to set up a configuration directive in order to be able to open files via HTTP, because by default file_get_contents() only works for local files.

See here for more explanations on how to do it:
http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: in php.ini is allow_url_fopen = on

Comment: `file_get_contents() only works for local files` its incorrect.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala From PHP docs: A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. **By default** they are disabled.