# text() returning wrong result

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox like this:

```
<li>  <input type="checkbox" name="collection[1]" value="1234"/>test</li>
```

When I use `$(this).text()` it should return `"test"` but it's returning `"   test"` (ie. with multiple spaces at the beginning)

I also checked the `innerText` property it has value as `"test"`.

Comment: you have space before the input inside the li. you can always use `.trim()`

Comment: also close your input tag

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360491/how-do-i-strip-white-space-when-grabbing-text-with-jquery

Comment: @edwin : it's not duplicate i checked multiple question before post.

Comment: @Pavan check the answers in here and answers in that question and you will see that they are the same.

Comment: @guradio i missed closeing input in question but it was there in code .i have updated the question. Your suggestion was right it was space issue

Comment: happy it worked now mate..happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context of your code sample, I assume `this` is a reference to the `li`. In which case the reason for the space preceding the text is because there's a space before it in the HTML.

If you want to remove the space either remove it from the HTML:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="collection[1]" value="1234" />test</li>
```

Or use `trim()` on the `text()` value you receive back to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
var text = $(this).text().trim();
```